# How to cancel a widget when creating by AppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget()?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-widget

If the user drags a widget normally to the home screen, then the configuration activity is started (if set). If the activity returns a result code of `RESULT_CANCELED`, then the widget creation is cancelled.
This is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets/configuration#update).

Alternativly, to add a widget from an activity, one can use `AppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget()`.
But then the configuration activity is not started, and the program should explicitly start it, as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager#requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.PendingIntent)).

This is my code that does it:

```kotlin
object StartWidgetConfigureReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        const val ACTION_NEW_WIDGET = "ACTION_NEW_WIDGET"

        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

            Intent(context, MyWidgetConfigureActivity::class.java).apply {
                action = ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE
                putExtras(intent)
                context?.startActivity(this)
            }

        }
    }
```

```kotlin
   val appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
   val myProvider = ComponentName(applicationContext, MyWidgetProvider::class.java)
   val successIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, 
             Intent(StartWidgetConfigureReceiver.ACTION_NEW_WIDGET),
             PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
   appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider,null, successIntent)
```

But how to cancel the widget if needed?

Adding `resultCode = Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` in `onReceive` does not seem to do it.

(I would need to wait for the result from the configuration activity, but that is not the question. Unless the way of starting the activity is relevant.)